# Prestashop - full name in Orders List - Back Office

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I am new to Prestashop 1.7

I need to show Firstname in order list in back office.

I found many answers for older versions of Prestashop but none for 1.7

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

Change the line 259 in src/Core/Grid/Query/OrderQueryBuilder.php

```
  return 'CONCAT(LEFT(cu.`firstname`, 1), \'. \', cu.`lastname`)';
```

For this:

```
 return 'CONCAT(cu.`firstname`, \' \', cu.`lastname`)';
```